# Por que meus eventos com Jquery param de funcionar depois de uma requisição AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Eu tenho dois botões que ao serem clicados fazem a chamada de um `.on('click',function())` mas antes disso é feita uma requisição AJAX e após essa requisição eles não funcionam mais. Antes de eu fazer a função para realizar a requisição ele funcionava perfeitamente. Essa é a requisição:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "teste.php",
     type: 'GET',
     success: function(html){
         var headline = $(html).find('#teste');                                                     
         $('#teste').html(headline);
     }   
 });
```

e o botão com o `.on('click')` é esse:

```
$('.remove-item').on('click',function(){alert('teste')});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Quando o elemento é inserido no DOM via javascript é necessário informar o selector do mesmo do mesmo.

**Exemplo:**

```
$('body').on('click', '.remove-item', function(){alert('teste')});
```

Answer (score 3):

Por ser uma requisição dinâmica (vinda do DOM) é necessário informar a classe onde ele está dentro, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
$('.minhaClasse').on('click', '.classeInterna', function() {
    alert('minha classe interna')
});
```

Caso contrário não irá funcionar, ou se estiver com mais de uma classe, pode ser que pegue a ultima classe apresentada.
Um exemplo com mais classes(por exemplo um for):

```
$('.minhaClasse').on('click', '.classeInterna', function() {
    var minhaImg = $(this).attr('src'); 
    console.log(minhImg); 
});
```

Pega o caminho da img clicada neste exemplo.